# Not Serializable: System.HttpResponse

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="newPageController">
  <apex:form >

      <apex:actionStatus id="status">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <div class="slds-spinner_container slds-is-relative  slds-spinner_container--fixed">
                    <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-is-relative"
                        aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
                        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>

      <apex:actionFunction name="callCheckRule" action="{!startRequest}" status="status"  rendered="result"></apex:actionFunction>

      <apex:commandButton action="{!startRequest}" status="status"
              value="Start Request" reRender="result"/> 
   </apex:form>

   <apex:outputText id="result"  >aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</apex:outputText>

</apex:page>
```

---

```
public without sharing class newPageController {
    // Unique label corresponding to the continuation
    public transient  String  requestLabel;
    // Result of callout
    public transient  String result {get;set;}

   public HttpRequest req;
   public HttpResponse resp;
   public String data{get;set;}
   public OpportunityLineItem oli;
    public Product2 prod;

   public newPageController(){
       OpportunityLineItem obj =[Select id,Product2Id from OpportunityLineItem where id =: '00k5D0000011111'];
       oli = obj;
        prod = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 where id =: oli.Product2Id];
   }

   // Action method
    public Void startRequest() {

     try{ 
       System.debug('Integration Handler START');

        String url;
        String body;
        //HttpRequest req;

        url = '';

        req = new HttpRequest();
        url  = EndpointURL;
        body += datetime.now().getTime()/1000;
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setBody(body);
        req.setheader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        system.debug('reqqqqqqqqqq'+req);
        Http h = new Http();
        resp = h.send(req);
        //return req; 
        data = resp.getBody();
        system.debug(resp+'respppppp'+resp.getBody());
        // this.requestLabel = con.addHttpRequest(req);


      // Return the continuation
      //return con;  

}catch(Exception e){
      System.debug('Exception at '+e.getLineNumber()+' '+e);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't include non-serializable classes as non-transient instance variables in a Visualforce controller, because the controller state has to be serialized to be stored as part of the view state.

Fortunately, your

```
public HttpRequest req;
public HttpResponse resp;
```

do not need to be instance variables at all. Simply move their declarations into the method body of `startRequest()`.